# Custom Intent broadcast

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

Android 8.0 (Oreo) introduced new optimizations of battery usage, including implicit BroadCast. We have the main app and extra installed plugins (apks). Main app sends custom Broadcast with action "POLL_PLUGINS" to determine which are installed and to share authorization data with them. The problem is that broadcast cannot be received in plugins on android 8.0. Here it is th code, which sends BroadCast:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction("<PACKAGE_NAME>.POLL_PLUGINS");
intent.putExtra ("auth", "<ENCRYPTED_DATA>"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And plugin's mainfest receiver:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".PluginReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100000000">
            <action android:name="<PACKAGE_NAME>.POLL_PLUGINS"/>
            <action android:name="<PACKAGE_NAME>.plugin1.START"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And plugin's receiver:

```
public class PluginReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d ("Plugin/Receiver","Plugin1 received data"); //<-- not being executed at all
        MainConn.parseBroadCastIntent (context,intent,R.mipmap.ico_crm, MainActivity.class);
    }
}
```

On previous androids works quite well. How can I use same scheme or are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

For more details see [details](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know about these restrictions and later Google plans to forbid apps publish which target sdk is less than 26.
Could you please explain how to use scheduled jobs for two apps (main app and plugin)?